# Windows7 Still Require a Product Key When has ProductKey Defined in Unattend File

Tags: windows, unattended

I am trying to build a system image by using Sysprep with an unattend file.

The key purpose is to let the end users choose their own username and computer name, but prevent them from typing the product key and manually activate it.

Here is my unattend.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="generalize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Licensing-SLC" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipRearm>1</SkipRearm>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Path>net user administrator /active:yes</Path>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipAutoActivation>false</SkipAutoActivation>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ShowWindowsLive>false</ShowWindowsLive>
            <TimeZone>New Zealand Standard Time</TimeZone>
            <ProductKey>AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEE</ProductKey>
            <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <CommandLine>cscript //b c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato</CommandLine>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                </SynchronousCommand>
            </FirstLogonCommands>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <NetworkLocation>Home</NetworkLocation>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
                <SkipMachineOOBE>false</SkipMachineOOBE>
                <SkipUserOOBE>false</SkipUserOOBE>
            </OOBE>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

And the sysprep command I issued:

```
sysprep /generalize /oobe /quit /unattend:unattend.xml
```

However, after I restored the image to a computer, it still prompts me the product key. What's wrong with my xml file?

---

**Update**

This installation disk doesn't require a product key during the installation. I guess this is the reason why the `<ProductKey>` line wouldn't work. But I still need the key pre-installed without user's interaction. How to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, Add the Windows-Shell-Setup component to the specialize pass and set the product key.
If you want automatic activation to be done, then you could try running a SynchronizedCommand in the specialize pass which would do :
cscript slmgr.vbs /ipk  /atoi

or simply

cscript slmgr.vbs /atoi

[Work with Product Keys and Activation | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/work-with-product-keys-and-activation-auth-phases)

Also you could check the link below if it is helpful.

[Windows 10 sysprep - how to skip entering product key - enter hostname | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1074940/windows-10-sysprep-how-to-skip-entering-product-key-enter-hostname)

Comment: That's not what I want. I have already included "SynchronousCommand" in my script.